# How to write a wrapper shell script for a java program in this case

Tags: java, shell, makefile, wrapper, gnu-make

everyone

Honestly I don't really know much about makefile... In my assignment, the description is that we must develop a Makefile for GNU make to build our program. For example, the command lines

```
make
mipsim -v < test1.cmd > test1.log
```

will build the ISS (a MIPS simulator we made) and then run it with debugging output(because of  "-v"), taking input commands from the file test1.cmd and writing result to test1.log.

My program has to read -v, test1.cmd and test1.log as three arguments probably to String[] args in the main function. I don't know how to make it happen....

I have finished the program but I don't know how to make the things above happen. What I know so far is that probably making a wrapper shell script that invokes the java program...

I also checked a lot about makefile... I got this

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
A.java \
mipsim.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
       $(RM) *.class
```

I know this makefile will just make .class files from .java. However, how could I make a wrapper shell script... I have no idea......

Thanks

Comment: Do you realize that the Java compiler may create more than one .class from a .java file?

Comment: If your mipsim-/A.java reads from System.in and write to System.out it does not make sense to pass file names to your program - which you've already been told elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in the directory where you have created the class files using the makefile shown in your question, you can execute these lines, assuming that `main` is in class `mipsim`:

```
java mipsim -v <test1.cmd >test1.log
```

Your `static void main(String[] args)` method has to access `args[0]` to get at the option `-v`.

A wrapper shell script for executing this could look like this

```
#! /bin/bash
file=$1
java mipsim -v <$file.cmd >$file.log
```

Call this file `mipsim`, set its execute permission bits and store it in the same directory. To invoke, type, e.g.

```
./mipsim test1
```

The initial `./` is required unless users happen to have this directory in their PATH (which they should rather not have). Also, it's best to hardwire the file name relation between cmd and log files - otherwise users will mistype, destroy old outputs, etc.

Comment: Thanks again.I tried your way. I created a file called mipsim.sh holding the wrapper shell script and put it in the same directory,then opened the terminal, cd to the directory, make, chmod +x mipsim.sh, java mipsim -v <test1.cmd >test1.log. Everything was fine so far. When I got to ./mipsim test1.cmd, it returned this -bash: ./mipsim: No such file or directory. So I tried mipsim test1.cmd, it returned -bash: mipsim: command not found. Then I just ignored the command ./mipsim test1, and java mipsim (run my program), an error just happened, args[0] got no element....

Comment: I didn't write "call it `mipsim.sh`", I wrote "call it `mipsim`". Also, kindly note that the basic command has been given as `java -v <test1.cmd >test1.log` - please note the `-v`. (But you should handle the absence of an option in your program anyway: this is called "defensive programming".) -- How about reading carefully what I wrote?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Now I have worked out all the things in this assignment. Please forgive me that I didn't get your idea exactly.. Anyway, thanks again!!